# Why inherited object property __proto__ reference to Object and not to the class which it inherit from?

Tags: javascript, console

I have the following code:

```
   const Person = function (firstName, birthYear) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.birthYear = birthYear;
};

Person.prototype.calcAge = function () {
  console.log(2037 - this.birthYear);
};

const Student = function (firstName, birthYear, course) {
  Person.call(this, firstName, birthYear);
  this.course = course;
};

// Linking prototypes
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
const stu = new Student("eitan",1986,"Math");
console.log(stu)
```

As I understand, stu.****proto**** should be equal to "Student" but actually it shows a "Person". Attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(stu)` is `Student.prototype`, not `Student`. Everything is in order. Don't be confused by the console output marking `Student.prototype` as a `Person` object.

Comment: What i have in the screenshot.. isn't it __proto__ /Object.getPrototypeOf(stu) of stu object? What does it mean: `__proto__:Person`?

Comment: It means that it's an object, and that the console believes it was constructed by `new Person` or has a `.constructor.name` of `Person`. Nothing more nothing less. Same how it says that `stu` is a `Student`.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype chain looks correct: Student > Person > Object.

Have you considered using `class`, instead? Inheritance is fairly straightforward.

Here's the same code using `class`, notice that the prototype chain is the same.

```js
class Person extends Object {
  constructor(firstName, birthYear) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
  }

  calcAge() {
    return 2037 - this.birthYear;
  }
}

class Student extends Person {
  constructor(firstName, birthYear, course) {
    super(firstName, birthYear);
    this.course = course;
  }
}

const stu = new Student('eitan', 1986, 'Math');

const pre = document.querySelector('pre');

pre.innerText = `stu:
${stu.constructor.name} ${JSON.stringify(stu, null, 2)}

stu.calcAge:
${stu.calcAge()}`;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Here's what the resulting `stu` looks like in a browser console, no change in the prototype chain:

[image]

Comment: tommorow i have video lecture on  how to create inheritence via classes.. today it was `Inheritance Between Classes Constructor Functions`.. It seems really easier this way.. I only need to understand what it the `<pre></pre>` :)

Comment: @Eitanos30 Was there no lecture on "Inheritance between objects" (i.e. using `Object.create`)? Because that's the most basic principle one needs to have understood…

Comment: @Bergi, there was.. it  was called `Inheritance Between "Classes": Object.create` .now i have just finished to watch it, and i really hope now i understand the issue.. I must admit that Java is much more intuitive than JS